# Session timeout in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, client-side, session-timeout

I am working on a Javascripyt/html mobile app and I want to implement the session timeout feature. The easiest way is to use the `setTimeout` function but I want to check if any click, change event was performed before I make the decision. The logic needs to be:

```
checkForSessionTimeout() {
      if(delta(last logged event time) <  session timeout time) {
              // do not timeout
              // reset the delta to 0
      } else {
              //timeout and take to login page
      }
}
```

I am able to get the function but not sure  **how do I log all click and change events on the browser**.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using jQuery? This example uses jQuery but you should be able to adapt it to whatever you are using: Listen for events on all DOM nodes. With jQuery, `$('*').on('click', function() ...)`. This will let you capture events even when a more close event binding has used `stopPropagation`.

It should work the same for change...

An example (open console): http://jsfiddle.net/u6eDj/2/

Comment: This makes sense. I am using XUI but the DOM manipulation is same. Thanks! :) Let me try and get back